# How do I use 'screencapture' on OS X

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm using OS X 10.6.5 and occasionally access it via ssh. While accessing it this way I need to be able to use the screencapture utility to take an image of the screen. The man page for screencapture says to do the following, but this doesn't seem to work for me:

```
SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS
     To capture screen content while logged in via ssh, you must launch
     screencapture in the same mach bootstrap hierarchy as loginwindow:

     PID=pid of loginwindow
     sudo launchctl bsexec $PID screencapture [options]
```

The command I'm using currently is:

```
sudo launchctl bsexec 53 screencapture foo.png
```

The result is that no PNG is outputted and the command silently returns. Can any of you help me make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this "gist" helps: https://gist.github.com/323256

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

screenshot="screnshot.png"
screencapture='/usr/sbin/screencapture -xC'

if [ `whoami` == 'root' ]; then
loginpid=`ps -ax | grep [l]oginwindow.app | awk '{print $1}'`
launchctl bsexec $loginpid $screencapture $screenshot
else
$screencapture $screenshot
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. That is a script that just makes it possible to repeatedly rerun what I'm doing. I did try those -xC arguments just for completeness sake, but it didn't change the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in via `ssh` to the same username currently logged in at the OS X main display.  You should then be able to run `screencapture` directly in the ssh session.